# Direct MySQL connection from react without any BackEnd Set-up

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, axios, react-router

I do want to create such a react-app where my client has only to click few buttons(based on different endpoints) such that react-app can fetch data from MySQL database. Now, the standard way to do so is to have a backend but is there any way where I can omit the backend.
Thanks in advance

Direct connection to database from react-app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Maybe you can use firebase or NodeJs as backend

Comment: yeah, I was also thinking the same. I had to somehow develop a backend for him.